# Alteração dos dados de identificação de um arquivo no upload

Tags: php, formulário, upload, file-upload

Estou tentando primeiramente, renomear um arquivo de acordo com o que o usuário nos fornecer, porém ocorre erro, mas é dado como `$_FILES["arquivo_foto"]["error"] -> 0`

Script de envio

```
<?php


$diretorioimagens = "arquivos/image/";
$uploadarquivo = $diretorioimagens . basename($_FILES["arquivo_foto"]["name"]);
$novonome = $_POST["novo_nome_foto"];
echo $novonome;
$_FILES["arquivo_foto"]["tmp_name"] = $novonome;
if($_FILES["arquivo_foto"]["size"] < 62914560){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["arquivo_foto"]["tmp_name"], $diretorioimagens)){
        echo "Enviado com sucesso com o nome " . $_FILES["arquivo_foto"]["tmp_name"];
    }else{
        echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, mais detalhes do erro abaixo <br>" . $_FILES["arquivo_foto"]["error"];
    }
}else{
    echo "Arquivo ultrapassa 60Mb";
};

?>
```

Formulário para envio da foto

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="envia_foto.php">
            <div>
                <label>Pré-visualização</label>
                <img src="" alt="Pré-visualização da imagem enviada">
            </div>
            <label>Nome do arquivo:
                <input type="text" name="novo_nome_foto" placeholder="Nome do arquivo">
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="hidden" value="62914560" name="">
                <input type="file" name="arquivo_foto" placeholder="Arquivo">
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
```

O que há de errado, e como posso corrigir ?

Comment: Se está usando hospedagem ou virtual (xampp)? verifique seu configuração php.ini para ativar file_uploads para ON, EDIT: Veja o exemplo mais simples https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está nessa linha:

```
$_FILES["arquivo_foto"]["tmp_name"] = $novonome;
```

Para alterar o nome do arquivo, não modifique o tmp_name, altere o nome na hora de copia-lo para o local definitivo, na funcao move_uploaded_file:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["arquivo_foto"]["tmp_name"], $diretorioimagens . $novonome)
```

E é muito importante você filtrar o novo nome para evitar confusão no seu sistema de arquivos, ou tentativa de salvar em pasta differente com algo do tipo:

```
// remove tudo que não for palavra, espaço, numero ou -_~,;[]()
$novonome = mb_ereg_replace("([^\w\s\d\-_~,;\[\]\(\).])", '', $novonome);
// remove pontos corridos 
$novonome = mb_ereg_replace("([\.]{2,})", '', $novonome);
```

Comment: $diretorioimagens já tem uma barra ao final do caminho.

Comment: Entendi, isso chama PATH, recomendo por pontuação um exemplo `$diretorioimagens = "./arquivos/image/"` .. Anderson disse é isso deve `/` esta certo, caso servidor independente o diretorio unix